# someone suggested I create a manga tag

Tags: discussion

How much rep do you need to create a new tag?
Or how does one create a new tag?
Honestly, I don't even know if we need a manga tag; I figured anime and naruto would be enough on the naruto question I asked earlier.
Thanks,

Comment: I'm not saying it is off-topic here, but there is an [Anime.SE](http://anime.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You need [300 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to create a new tag.

All you need to do to create a new tag is to enter the tag in the tag section of a question.  If the tag doesn't exist, no tool tip matching it will appear, and the tag will be created once you save the question.

In this case, all I did was type "manga" after the existing [anima](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anima) and [naruto](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto).

Always remember to try and create a tag wiki and/or excerpt for tags you create, if you can (I'm going to take a stab at [manga](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) in a minute).

Answer (score 3):

If we have a question that is about a manga (as opposed to an anime), then it should be appropriately tagged.  If you've seen a question that meets that description, link it, and someone will tag it appropriately.

Comment: There currently is no manga tag; and the question applies to both anime and manga. here's the question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38991/why-didnt-the-third-hokage-choose-another-successor-after-minato-died